# Multiprocessing.Manager() weird behavior with global variables

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables, python-multiprocessing

I have a problem with the `multiprocessing.Manager` class which have a very weird behavior when the manager objects are global variables.

**code 1 :**

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()

list1 = manager.list(range(4))
dict1 = manager.dict({"d":1,"f":2})

def process1(list1,dict1):
    print "process1"
    dict1["3"] = 123
    list1.append(10)

def run():
    print "start"
    global list1
    global dict1

    print "list1",list1
    print "dict1",dict1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "start"
    j = multiprocessing.Process(target=process1, args=(list1,dict1))
    j.start()
    j.join()
    run()
```

**Output 1:**

```sh
start
process1
start
list1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 10]
dict1 {'3': 123, 'd': 1, 'f': 2}
```

Ok, that means that global variables `̀list1` and `dict1` have been modified by `process1`.

The problem is that when I try to replace `list1` or `dict1` it doesn't work!

**code 2 :**

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()

list1 = manager.list(range(4))
dict1 = manager.dict({"d":1,"f":2})

def process1(list1,dict1):
    print "process1"
    dict1["3"] = 123
    list1 = manager.list(range(100,104))

def run():
    print "start"
    global list1
    global dict1

    print "list1",list1
    print "dict1",dict1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "start"
    j = multiprocessing.Process(target=process1, args=(list1,dict1))
    j.start()
    j.join()
    run()
```

**Output 2:**

```sh
start
process1
start
list1 [0, 1, 2, 3]
dict1 {'3': 123, 'd': 1, 'f': 2}
```

Any idea why it returns the initial list `[0, 1, 2, 3]` instead of `[100, 101, 102, 103]`?

Answer (score 0):

While a `Manager.list` object is shared across processes, the *names* you bind to that object aren't shared at all - not even if you use the same name in all processes.  `global` means the same binding is seen throughout the module in the process that's running the module (unless overridden in some local scope); it doesn't magically mean more than that just because `multiprocessing` was imported ;-)

Specifically, the name `list1` in the main process has nothing to do with the name `list1` in the worker process.  Their only relation is that both names happen to be initially bound to a single, shared instance of `Manager.list`.  Which is usually all you want from them.  Rebinding the name `list1` to some other object, in either process, has no effect on the object the name `list1` is bound to in any other process.

So, in your second example, within the worker process the name `list1` becomes (re)bound to a new `manager.list(range(100,104))` instance.  This has no effect whatsoever on the binding of name `list1` in the main process.  Nor is there any possible way for the worker process to change the bindings of any names in any other process - and it would be a nightmare if that could happen.

You can change shared object *values*, though.  But you appear to already know that.  For example, doing

```
list1[:] = range(100,104)
```

instead changes no bindings, but replaces the entire content of the shared `Manager.list` instance (so the main process will see the new list content too not because the *names* are the same, but because both names are bound to the same *object*).

By the way, note that in your `process1` function, `list1` isn't even a global name anyway.  It's the name of one of the function's arguments, so acts like a function-local variable name.

Short course:  stop thinking about names, and think instead in terms of objects.  Names are never shared across processes.